# How can I redirect process output (console) using avrdude to richtextbox?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use this code to run an avrdude process and redirect process output (console) to richtextbox, everything works perfectly except sending the text to Richtextbox, I tried to put another cmd command as help, and it works perfectly.
I tried in several ways, both synchronously and asynchronously and when it comes to the avrdude file nothing is captured.

```
void SortOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(e.Data);
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        txtconsole.Focus();
        txtconsole.AppendText(e.Data ?? string.Empty);
    }));
}
private void OnOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (syncGate)
    {
        if (sender != process) return;
        output.AppendLine(e.Data);
        if (outputChanged) return;
        outputChanged = true;
        BeginInvoke(new Action(OnOutputChanged));
    }
}

private void ReadData()
{
    var input = process.StandardOutput;
    int nextChar;
    while ((nextChar = input.Read()) >= 0)
    {
        lock (syncGate)
        {
            output.Append((char)nextChar);
            if (!outputChanged)
            {
                outputChanged = true;
                BeginInvoke(new Action(OnOutputChanged));
            }
        }
    }
    lock (syncGate)
    {
        process.Dispose();
        process = null;
    }
}

private void OnOutputChanged()
{
    lock (syncGate)
    {
        txtconsole.Text = output.ToString();
        outputChanged = false;
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Directory == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selecione o arquivo de atualização para continuar.");
    }
    else
    {

        lock (syncGate)
        {
            if (process != null) return;
        }

        output.Clear();
        outputChanged = false;
        txtconsole.Text = "";

        process = new Process();
        string workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = $"{workingDirectory}/avrdude/avrdude.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"avrdude -c avrispmkII -p m2560 -U flash:w:{Directory}:i -P usb";
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();

        new Thread(ReadData) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"avrdude process output" has not 'StandardOutput' but 'StandardError'.
Please try to redirect 'StandardError'.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ...
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 ...
```

```
private void ReadData()
{
  var input = process.StandardError;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).